# strlen assembly returns 6 for short strings

Tags: assembly, x86-64

last week in lab we had to implement a strlen function in x86_64 assembly.  I finished the lab and got full credit but later saw that there was a mistake in my code.  For long strings it works fine but for strings of length 1,2,3,or 4 my function returns 6. I don't understand why.  Below is the code.

```
    .text
        .globl mystrlen
  .type   mystrlen, @function
  mystrlen:
        movq $0, %rax                   #put 0 in return register
        movq $0, %r15
        beginloop:
        cmpq $0, (%rdi)         #while n!=0
        je end
        incq %rax
        incq %rdi
        movq $0, %r14
        cmpq $0, %r14                   #go back to bginning
        je beginloop
      end:                          #
          ret                       # return result;
```

Now I know this is not a good way to implement strlen and there are things I can take advantage of to make this efficient, but I don't really care. I'm just trying to figure out why this code returns 6 for strings of length 1, 2, 3, or 4.  It does return correctly for strings of length 0 or greater than 5.  Please help me understand

Comment: When you use `cmpq $0, (%rdi)`, how many bytes are you comparing?

Answer (score 3):

Bo Persson already pointed out where the problem is.
instead of using cmpq, you should use cmpb (comparing with byte)